# Passing dynamic parameters to a function (VisualForce)

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-button

I want to pass a dynamic parameter from a Visualforce into a custom apex controller. This parameter is in a table and will have a Contact's id associated with each row on the button that is being pressed to execute my custom function. The problem I'm having right now is that it demands that I pass in an expression.

**EDIT:**

This is the signature I'm trying to use - `public PageReference addMemberToCase(string memberID)` And it's going to be executed via a command button. So I'd want the apex code to look like this - `<apex:commandButton value="Add to Case" styleClass="btn btn-primary addBtn" id="memberID=SomehowDynamicID?" action="{!addMemeberToCase({!a.contact.id})}"/>`

Here's a photo of a row that I'm trying to create [TABLE ROW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIl3o.png)

Comment: and how do you want to pass in?

Comment: This is the signature I'm trying to use - `public PageReference addMemberToCase(string memberID)` And it's going to be executed via a command button. So I'd want the apex code to look like this - `<apex:commandButton value="Add to Case" styleClass="btn btn-primary addBtn" id="memberID=SomehowDynamicID?"
                                    action="{!addMemeberToCase({!a.contact.id})}"/>`

Comment: I don't think you mean `static`. That sounds quite stateful.

Comment: Maybe static isn't the right word. What I mean is that each button is going to have it's own id based on the contact's Id that is going to be filling that row of a table.

Comment: Here's an image of a row from the table I'm creating - [Table Row](http://i.imgur.com/4fju3e0.png)

Comment: Can you update your question to include any code that's relevant? It's not easy to read in comments.

Comment: Yeah you pretty much meant the exact opposite of static. I changed it to dynamic to better fit what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is have instance variables in your custom controller and assign your parameters dynamically in your visual force page.

In your controller:

```
    ID myID {get;set;}

    public void addMemberToCase()
    {
        Id IdOfMember = this.myID;'
        //do your logic here
    }
```

In your visualforce page:

```
    <apex:element ......>
       <apex:actionSupport action="{!addMemberToCase()}">
          <apex:param assignTo="{!myID}" value="{!repeaterVar.ID}" />
       </apex:actionSupport>
    <apex:element ......>
```